# how do i stop ios from automatically adding cookie to my NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, cookies

i am hitting a url with the following code:

```
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequestHttp returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];
```

and i have theRequestHttp initialized here:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequestHttp = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
```

no where do i have the cookie being added to the urlrequest... in fact, i have the following set:

```
[theRequestHttp addValue:nil forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
```

i also tried with

```
[theRequestHttp setValue:nil forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
```

is there any way to NOT add the Cookie?

Comment: could i have a reason why i got down votes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
```

Comment: thank you for your response. i will try this and get back with the results in a day. hopefully this solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can disable automatic addition of cookies but you can delete cookies anytime you want using the following code

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in storage.cookies) {

      [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Comment: tried this :-( still have cookies being sent for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, this is a method to do this, this method sets a cookie after implementing your own cookie info, and the category below this method powers this method, this will work by sniping the EXSISTING cookie right after you make the cookie methos above and then you mutate the cookie to whatever data you want, you will still have a cookie, but it won't be useful unless you are replacing the cookie info with real info. You can just immediatley look through the array of cookies and delete them. Either way, you can make cookies NOT work and get rid of them:

```
- (void)manipulateCookie {
    NSArray* cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
    for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in cookies) {
        NSString *alipaySetCookieString = @"CAKEPHP=nil; path=#; domain=#; expires=Wed, 30-Nov-2001 01:01:01 GMT";
        NSHTTPCookie * clok  = [alipaySetCookieString cookie];
        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:clok];
    }
}
```

category:

NSString+Cookie.h

```
@interface NSString(Cookie)
- (NSHTTPCookie *)cookie;
@end
```

NSString+Cookie.m

```
#import "NSString+Cookie.h"

@implementation NSString(Cookie)

- (NSDictionary *)cookieMap {
    NSMutableDictionary *cookieMap = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSArray *cookieKeyValueStrings = [self componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    for (NSString *cookieKeyValueString in cookieKeyValueStrings) {
        NSRange separatorRange = [cookieKeyValueString rangeOfString:@"="];

        if (separatorRange.location != NSNotFound &&
            separatorRange.location > 0 &&
            separatorRange.location < ([cookieKeyValueString length] - 1)) {

            NSRange keyRange = NSMakeRange(0, separatorRange.location);
            NSString *key = [cookieKeyValueString substringWithRange:keyRange];
            NSString *value = [cookieKeyValueString substringFromIndex:separatorRange.location + separatorRange.length];

            key = [key stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
            value = [value stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
            [cookieMap setObject:value forKey:key];
        }
    }
    return cookieMap;
}

- (NSDictionary *)cookieProperties {
    NSDictionary *cookieMap = [self cookieMap];
    NSMutableDictionary *cookieProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString *key in [cookieMap allKeys]) {

        NSString *value = [cookieMap objectForKey:key];
        NSString *uppercaseKey = [key uppercaseString];
        if ([uppercaseKey isEqualToString:@"DOMAIN"]) {
            if (![value hasPrefix:@"."] && ![value hasPrefix:@"www"]) {
                value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".%@",value];
            }
            [cookieProperties setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookieDomain];
        }else if ([uppercaseKey isEqualToString:@"VERSION"]) {
            [cookieProperties setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookieVersion];
        }else if ([uppercaseKey isEqualToString:@"MAX-AGE"]||[uppercaseKey isEqualToString:@"MAXAGE"]) {
            [cookieProperties setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookieMaximumAge];
        }else if ([uppercaseKey isEqualToString:@"PATH"]) {
            [cookieProperties setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookiePath];
        }else if([uppercaseKey isEqualToString:@"ORIGINURL"]){
            [cookieProperties setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookieOriginURL];
        }else if([uppercaseKey isEqualToString:@"PORT"]){
            [cookieProperties setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookiePort];
        }else if([uppercaseKey isEqualToString:@"SECURE"]||[uppercaseKey isEqualToString:@"ISSECURE"]){
            [cookieProperties setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookieSecure];
        }else if([uppercaseKey isEqualToString:@"COMMENT"]){
            [cookieProperties setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookieComment];
        }else if([uppercaseKey isEqualToString:@"COMMENTURL"]){
            [cookieProperties setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookieCommentURL];
        }else if([uppercaseKey isEqualToString:@"EXPIRES"]){
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";
            [cookieProperties setObject:[dateFormatter dateFromString:value] forKey:NSHTTPCookieExpires];
        }else if([uppercaseKey isEqualToString:@"DISCART"]){
            [cookieProperties setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookieDiscard];
        }else if([uppercaseKey isEqualToString:@"NAME"]){
            [cookieProperties setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
        }else if([uppercaseKey isEqualToString:@"VALUE"]){
            [cookieProperties setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
        }else{
            [cookieProperties setObject:key forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
            [cookieProperties setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
        }
    }
    if (![cookieProperties objectForKey:NSHTTPCookiePath]) {
        [cookieProperties setObject:@"/" forKey:NSHTTPCookiePath];
    }
    return cookieProperties;
}

- (NSHTTPCookie *)cookie {
    NSDictionary *cookieProperties = [self cookieProperties];
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieProperties];
    return cookie;
}

@end
```

Comment: hey its mike, are you available for the chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87214/room-for-larcerax-and-mike-strong

Comment: sorry about that. will try this first thing tomorrow morning and try this out. been on the road for the last 2 days.